# PyQt5 рисование по нажанию клавиши

Tags: python

Мне надо, чтобы нарисованная картинка при нажатии клавиши сдвигалась и видоизменялась. Использую QPainter, ругается, что

> QPainter::drawPoints: Painter not active.

Такие дела. Помогите горе-студенту :) Чем лучше пользоваться для динамической отрисовки картинки? Или, может, я каких-то заклинаний не знаю?

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    self.sk = QtGui.QPainter()
    self.sk.begin()
    self.drawBack()
    self.drawStars()
    self.sk.end()

def drawBack(self): 
    white_pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('white'), 3)
    self.sk.setPen(white_pen)
    self.sk.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('midnightblue'))
    self.sk.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

def drawStars(self):
    self.sk.setPen(QtGui.QColor('white'))
    size = self.size()

    if self.stars:
        for a in self.stars:
            self.sk.drawPoint(a.x - 1, a.y)
    else:
        for i in range(10):
            x = random.randint(1, size.width()-1)
            y = random.randint(1, size.height()-1)
            self.stars.add(StarAndDec(x, y))
            self.sk.drawPoint(x, y)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):

    key = event.key()

    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
       for a in self.stars:
           a.x = a.x - 1
           self.drawStars()`
```

Answer (score 1):

Отрисовка в QPainter может использоваться только в его `paintEvent`, поместите код отрисовки в нее.
В `keyPressEvent`  поместите строчку `sk.update()` чтобы вызвать то событие.